# What is the right way to design a point and click game with Lua?(Corona)

Tags: lua, coronasdk, moai

I have some ideas,I have already drawn the scenes roughly and put them into corona.
This is how I would think it would work.

  1.I have all the
  *major scenes*

2.In each *major scene* ,there are *mini scenes*,which lead to *smaller scenes* with puzzles.

3.I create a game.lua module so it would handle the game logics,and keep track of them.

Example:

```
  A.Door is opened,puzzle number one is solved.
  B.Send a costume event to the game module.
```

4.I need a separate module for *inventory box* so it acts as an overlay over other scenes.
It also interacts with game module. 
.

  I know you might say,wait till you get started,but Am I on the right Track?

Do you have better suggestions or know any code examples(Corona Sdk,Lua,Moai,GiderosMobile)?
.
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are just starting out, don't worry about setting up this high level architectural stuff. Just do *something* and get a game working. Any time some part of the game code sucks, work on fixing that specific thing. And be prepared to throw your first attempt away. Your question is too broad, and until you have some concrete question about a specific thing you want to do you're going to have a hard time getting help.

Comment: I absolutely agree with you.That is what I am doing at the moment,But I wanted to hear some feed backs anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am making a game more or less on this style using Corona, there are a [beta on google play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kidoteca.nonoamazonia.beta).

Corona SDK offers a API named Storyboard, that API allow you to code each scene as a lua module, and allows also you to load a scene as a "overlay".

I guess that you would make each of your scenes a full Storyboard scene, and the inventory a "overlay" scene.

The difference between overlay to a normal scene, is that when you load a overlay it triggers a event on the scene that was open instead of unloading that scene (And when the overlay is unloaded, it triggers another event)

So yes, at least if you do it in Corona, you are in the right track!

Comment: Thanks.I have already used storyboards for all my rough scenes.I was wondering ,if I need a separate game.lua for the game logic.At least That is what I am planning to do.